# The correct usage of tags Chat Support mobile-web 'bug-feature request discussion support'

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

I am new here. I was wanting to know if you can use tags whenever I am answering another person's questions? Tags have me a bit confused?

Chat Support mobile-web 'bug-feature request discussion support'.

Comment: Tags only go on questions, not an answers. They are meant so users can find the questions to answer.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to me.